# What does new(new() { Args = args }); mean?

Tags: c#

In namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder in the class WebApplication there is this strange syntax in line 98 or 106. What does this mean?

```
 public static WebApplicationBuilder CreateBuilder() =>
        new(new());


 public static WebApplicationBuilder CreateBuilder(string[] args) =>
        new(new() { Args = args });
```

Comment: @CodeCaster It's not an anonymous object, but its type is inferred from context by the compiler. `new()` is not  anonymouse, `new {}` is.

Comment: It is twice a "[target-typed new expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new)". It basically states `=> new WebApplicationBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions { Args = args }))`. See duplicate.

Comment: @Zohar I don't know how I missed the `()` twice, thanks.